# What should I use (sqlite or Shared preferences) to store lat-lng of entire trip locally in android? trip can be very long i.e upto 3 days

Tags: android, location, android-sqlite, sharedpreferences

I want to store the latlng of entire trip by user.The location update time is set to 10s. What should I use shared preference or sqlite to save all location points in android device locally?
The trip can be very long i.e 3-4 days.

Comment: maximum 5000 LatLng points

Comment: yes i saved encoded polyline in Sharedpreference but to add new point i have decode the string, add point to list, encode it into polyline and then save it to sharedPreference.

Answer (score 0):

Shared preference it's a key-> value storage. Of course you can store complex data for value but is not recommended. You should use a database(sqlite) for storing so many values. I suppose you also want to query stuff so shared preference ain't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use database, shared preferences is only for using small key-value variables.